# Tela de autenticação com SQLite

Tags: java, android, sqlite

Tenho que realizar a autenticação do usuário, porem quando informo o usuário e a senha correta ele entra na tela de menu, até ai tudo bem. O problema é que quando digito uma senha ou usuario incorreto, quero que apresente uma mensagem usuário não encontrado, o problema é que quando é para aparecer o Toast com a mensagem o app para.

Método de pesquisa no banco

```
    public Usuario UsuarioAutenticar (String user, String senha){

    Usuario usuario = new Usuario ();

    String autenticarSQL = "SELECT * FROM tblUsuario WHERE usuario = '" + user +"' and senha = '"+senha+"'";

    sqLiteDatabase = bancoDados.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = sqLiteDatabase.rawQuery(autenticarSQL,null);

    cursor.moveToFirst();

    usuario.setIdUsuario(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));
    usuario.setNome(cursor.getString(1).toString());
    usuario.setCpf(cursor.getString(2).toString());
    usuario.setEmail(cursor.getString(3).toString());
    usuario.setTelefone(cursor.getString(4).toString());
    usuario.setUser(cursor.getString(5).toString());
    usuario.setSenha(cursor.getString(6).toString());

    return usuario;
}
```

Método botão Login

public void btAcessarOnClick (View view){

```
    usuario = usuarioDAO.UsuarioAutenticar(edUsuario.getText().toString(), edSenha.getText().toString());

    if(usuario!=null) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(ActivityLogin.this, ActivityMenu.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
    else
        Toast.makeText(this, "Usuario não encontrado", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Logcat

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Mostre o `Logcat`, por favor.

Comment: Segue acima no post

Comment: `CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: index 0 requested, with a size of 0`

Answer (score 2):

Ola, 
Como voce setou `Usuario usuario = new Usuario ();`   no metodo que autentica mesmo que não exista no bd o retorno nunca sera null, sera apenas um objeto usuario sem informações....

Parece que ao pedir o indice 0 do cursor ele esta dando IndexOutOfBounds pois não encontrou no banco.....

tente alterar de `sqLiteDatabase = bancoDados.getWritableDatabase();`

para

```
sqLiteDatabase = bancoDados.getReadableDatabase();
```

pois voce não precisa alterar o bd, apos isso substitua no codigo:

```
if(cursor!=null){
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    usuario.setIdUsuario(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));
    usuario.setNome(cursor.getString(1).toString());
    usuario.setCpf(cursor.getString(2).toString());
    usuario.setEmail(cursor.getString(3).toString());
    usuario.setTelefone(cursor.getString(4).toString());
    usuario.setUser(cursor.getString(5).toString());
    usuario.setSenha(cursor.getString(6).toString());
}else{
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Tente da seguinte forma:

```
    public Usuario UsuarioAutenticar (String user, String senha){
    final SQLiteDatabase db = bancoDados.getReadableDatabase();


    /**
     Aqui você deve colocar todas as colunas que deseja recuperar
     */
    final String[] properties = {"idusuario", "nome", "cpf", "email", "senha", "user", "telefone"};


    /**
     * Vamos criar uma query
     * Informamos:
     * 1. Nome da tabela
     * 2. propriedades que vamos recuperar
     * 3. Condições ( WHERE )
     * 4. Parametros das condições (refere se ao ?) Para cada ? deve haver um parametro neste array
     */
    final Cursor cursor = db.query("tblUsuario", properties, "usuario = ? and senha = ?", new String[]{user, senha}, null, null, null, null);

    /**
     * Este método retornará false se o cursor estiver vazio.
     */
    if(cursor.moveToFirst()){
       final Usuario usuario = new Usuario ();
        usuario.setIdUsuario(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));
        usuario.setNome(cursor.getString(1).toString());
        usuario.setCpf(cursor.getString(2).toString());
        usuario.setEmail(cursor.getString(3).toString());
        usuario.setTelefone(cursor.getString(4).toString());
        usuario.setUser(cursor.getString(5).toString());
        usuario.setSenha(cursor.getString(6).toString());

        return usuario;
    }else{
        return null;
    }
}
```